# Exibir duas ActionResult do mesmo Controller na página Index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Já estou exibindo uma tabela na Index, só que quero exibir uma outra tabela do mesmo controller. Criei uma `PartialView` chamada `PartCorteCabos()` e criei uma View dela. Tentei fazer a chamada usando `@Html.Partial()`, mas não exibe as informações vindas do banco de dados. Como faço para exibir a segunda tabela?

**Controller**

```
public class DashboardSPMController : Controller
{
    DashboardSPMRepository dashRepository = new DashboardSPMRepository();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(dashRepository.InfoReceb());
    }

    public ActionResult PartCorteCabos()
    {
        return PartialView(dashRepository.InfoCorteCabos());
    }
}
```

**PartCorteCabos (Partial View)**

```
@model IEnumerable<WAM.Areas.Monitoramentos.Models.Entities.DashboardSPM>

@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(column =>
   {
      column.Add(x => x.prioridade_cc).Titled("Prioridade");
      column.Add(x => x.sales_order_cc).Titled("SO's");
      column.Add(x => x.delivery_cc).Titled("Delivery");
      column.Add(x => x.material_cc).Titled("P/N");
   })
```

**Index View**

```
@model IEnumerable<WAM.Areas.Monitoramentos.Models.Entities.DashboardSPM>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Master.cshtml";
}
        <div>
            <span class="titulo">
                <p>Status Recebimento</p>
            </span>
            <span class="size-tab">
                @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(column =>
                {
                   column.Add(x => x.material).Titled("Itens 902");
                   column.Add(x => x.lead_time).Titled("LT");
                   column.Add(x => x.lotes_nac).Titled("Lote Nacional");
                   column.Add(x => x.lotes_imp).Titled("Lote Importado");
                   column.Add(x => x.sb).Titled("SB's");
                   column.Add(x => x.danfe).Titled("DANFE's");
                })
            </span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <span class="titulo">
                <p>Corte Cabos</p>
            </span>
             @Html.Partial("PartCorteCabos")
        </div>
```

Comment: Como  não  exibe os valores vindo do banco   ? passar o model  para sua view ?

Comment: Na primeira 'div' os dados são exibidos normalmente. Mas na segunda 'div' os dados não são exibidos, só aparece o nome das colunas mas os dados não aparecem.

Comment: @MarcosBrinner consegui fazer exibir. Troquei a forma que estava chamando a PartialView. Ao invés de chamar dessa forma @Html.Partial("PartCorteCabos"), que é a forma que esta no código a cima, chamei da seguinte forma @Html.Action("PartCorteCabos").

Comment: A model declarada na Partial não deveria ser do mesmo tipo recebido em `InfoCorteCabos()`? Vejo que na controller você tem dois métodos diferentes e na nas views você está indicando a mesma model

Comment: Os dados estão dentro de apenas uma Model que é a DashboardSPM

Comment: Mas ambos os métodos, `dashRepository.InfoReceb()` e `dashRepository.InfoCorteCabos()` retornam uma `DashboardSPM`? Inclua a estrutura dela na pergunta

Comment: Sim, ambas retornam uma DashboarsSPM. Não sei se o modo que fiz foi a melhor, acho que não, pois estou aprendendo ainda. Mas resolveu meu problema. Se tiver uma melhor forma de exibir os dados, gostaria de  saber para aprender.

Comment: Não seria ideal você chamar um RenderAction(ControllerAction) na sua view, onde o seu controller ficaria responsavel por retornar a ControllerAction com o seu model?